# How to use "String.prototype" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to use a String.prototype to create a function that can hide elements in js. My code is written below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="id"></h1>
</body>
<script>
String.prototype.hide = () => {
  return "style.display=none;"
}
document.getElementById("id").hide();
</script>
</html>
```

this gives me an error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hide')

I am trying to find out how to use this for a long time. Please help me!!!

Comment: `String.prototype` adds the method to the string object. Not an element. You'd need to use `'mystring'.hide()` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: [`document.getElementById` returns an Element object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), not a string, so `String.prototype` isn't relevant. It's not really clear how you expected this to work - the `"style.display=none;"` isn't run or saved anywhere.

Comment: Also, even if that was possibile, it would be considered a bad practice. Indeed, changing the prototype of built-in object can be confusing or dangerous. Just take a good JavaScript tutorial and all this will be clear to you

Comment: _"i want to use a String.prototype to create a function that can hide elements"_ - That's a terrible idea. Where's the connection between a string and the visibility of an element in the DOM? o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were going to augment a built-in prototype to do this, it would make more sense to augment `Element.prototype`, not `String.prototype`, since what you're trying to use `hide` on isn't a string, it's an `HTMLElement` instance (which inherits from `Element`).

But it's **usually not a good idea** to augment/extend the built-in prototypes. It's fragile. If two scripts in the same page do it using the same name, they interfere with each other. If the DOM later gets a `hide` method, that messes up your existing code. Etc. Better to have a function you pass the element into:

```js
function hide(element) {
    element.style.display = "none";
}

setTimeout(() => {
    hide(document.getElementById("id"));
}, 800);
```

```html
<h1 id="id">Hi there</h1>
```

But if you do do it, make the extension non-enumerable by using `defineProperty`:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "hide", {
    value() {
        this.style.display = "none";
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false, // This is the default, but I'm including it for emphasis...
});

setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("id").hide();
}, 800);
```

```html
<h1 id="id">Hi there</h1>
```

If you really, really wanted to, you could do this on `String.prototype` by assuming the string is the `id` of an element (or a selector for an element). For instance:

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "hide", {
    value() {
        const element = document.getElementById(this);
        if (element) {
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false, // This is the default, but I'm including it for emphasis...
});

setTimeout(() => {
    "id".hide();
}, 800);
```

```html
<h1 id="id">Hi there</h1>
```

But I wouldn't do that. :-)